# java.lang.IllegalStateException at super.onTouchEvent(event)

Tags: android, touch-event, illegalstateexception

After waking up my phone and touching the display I get the following error message:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230724, class eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]

So, I already found the location in the code that is repsonsible for this error message:

```
public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView{
    ...other code...


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        // it also crashes although I make this check
        if( !(  Looper.getMainLooper().equals(Looper.myLooper()) ) ) 
                return true;

        ... other code in this method...

        return super.onTouchEvent(event); <-- it crashes exactly here at the end of the whole method
    }
```

So, I check if I'm on the uithread and it still crashes? So probably I'm doing something wrong in this if line?
Additionally, since this is a class that extends a listview I'm not able to use

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

// runnable code here.

});
```

So my question: How do I repair this? Currently I've got no idea...

Comment: Are you saving the data backed by your ListView during config changes or in onSaveInstaceState? I suspect your data model backing your ListView is getting wiped out.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have not implemented onSaveInstanceState()